# How to transfer ico tokens to myetherwallet, Metamask programmatically

Tags: go-ethereum, blockchain, erc-20, etherscan, ico

I am working on an ICO site. Everything is working fine now i need to transfer ICO token to Myetherwallet and metamask wallet. Please let me know what are the best and possible ways to do this and is it possible in php?.

Answer (score 1):

First, something you should have understood before working with something: the wallet concept.

A wallet is not "metamask" or "myetherwallet". A wallet, or account, is just an ethereum address and all related stuff (public/private key, ...).

Your wallet is not "in metamask" or in "myetherwallet". Metamask or mew are just tools to use your address. Your address is just an ID to identify you, you can use it anywhere as long as you have its keystore or private key.

Now, to send transactions: Not possible in PHP yet. It is possible in javascript, python, java. The "library" is called web3 (all github repos here: [repo](https://github.com/ethereum)

For web3js, here is the [github](https://github.com/ethereum/web3.js) and here the [documentation](https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/1.0/)

Comment: I have read and found this module in php https://github.com/sc0Vu/web3.php. Can you please let me know the process and other requirements   on my local and live server.